# Field values are added to collection as null with React Hooks + Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm working on a React Native app and I have a form I want to post to Firestore using React Hooks. It's almost working, but the field values show up as null in Firebase. What am I doing wrong?
Using 
react-native 0.60.5 and
react-native-firebase 5.6.0. Thanks in advance!

```
const [ trackTitle, setTitle ] = useState('')
const [ artistName, setArtist ] = useState('')
```

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    firestore()
    .collection('tracks')
        .add(
          {
          trackTitle,
          artistName
        })
}
```

```
<TextInput 
     value={trackTitle} 
     onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
     style={styles.submissionInput}
     multiline={false}
/> 

<TextInput 
     value={artistName} 
     onChange={e => setArtist(e.target.value)}
     style={styles.submissionInput}
     multiline={false}
/>
```

```
<TouchableOpacity
     onPress={onSubmit}
     style={styles.navButtons}>
```

Screenshot of the Firebase console:

[image]

Comment: If you change your submit function to `function onSubmit(e) {
console.log(trackTitle, artistName);   
 firestore()
    .collection('tracks')
        .add(
          {
          trackTitle,
          artistName
        })
}`
What values are logged to the console?

Comment: @LenJoseph I get this:  2020-04-12 21:34:22.578 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined, undefined
2020-04-12 21:34:22.578072-0700 *appname* [45583:824514] undefined, undefined

Comment: Ok, so you're setting the state with undefined before you even submit the data to Firestore. Try logging `e.target.value` to the console and see if that value is what you think it is when you pass it to `setTitle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the value you want is not in e.target.value, but in e.text, so `onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}`, should be `onChange={e => setTitle(e.text)}`

However, I would suggest you use `onChangeText={newValue => setTitle(newValue)}` and better yet, `onChangeText={setTitle}`

[RN Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext)

```
<TextInput 
     value={trackTitle} 
     onChangeText={setTitle}
     style={styles.submissionInput}
     multiline={false}
/> 

<TextInput 
     value={artistName} 
     onChangeText={setArtist}
     style={styles.submissionInput}
     multiline={false}
/>
```